# Jquery - Select tab via url

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery code that allows me to use tabs, to tab back and fourth between content/divs. My question is using the code below, how could I have it load the initial tab based on a variable in the url? So if I go to somesite.com/page.php#tab2, then instead of tab1 loading by default tab2 loads:

```
$('.tabcontent > div').hide();
$('.tabcontent > div:first-child').show();
$('.tabs > li:first-child').addClass('selected');
$('.tabs > li a').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('href');
    $(tab_id).parent().children().hide();
    $(tab_id).fadeIn();
    $(this).parent().parent().children().removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    return false;
});
```

**EDIT**

Just to note this code is a click event, however if I want to change the tab via the url the person loads then it wont work unless they click a tab. So how can I get it to listen for a click and listen to see if there is a value present in the current url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gup function,found [here](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html):

```
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

This will allow you to read a URL parameter and use it to navigate to the selected tab.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help: -

```
var tab_id = $(this).attr('href');
var split = tab_id.split('#');
    split = split[1];

if (split = "page 2") {

window.alert(split);

} else {
 // Default condition   

}
```

JS Fiddle Example here - http://jsfiddle.net/aNMBW/

Answer (score 0):

Detecting changes on the URL fragment (#whatever) is hard to do crossbrowser without a little help. I usually use Ben Alman's BBQ plugin:

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-jquery-ui-tabs/

If I'm misunderstanding and you just want to load a tab based on the INITIAL url, you could just do it by detecting the hash:

```
...
if(window.location.hash){
  $(".tabs > li a[href=" + window.location.hash + "]").click();
}
```

This assumes that your tab is linking to href="#foo", and that the URL you visit is mysite.com/pagename#foo

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hash value in a url using `window.location.hash`. From there, you just need to do some slight checking to determine what tab should be shown.

[Here's a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/g7F87/1/). Please note that we can't actually use `window.location.hash` in jsFiddle because it uses iFrames, which means the address you see in the browser's address bar isn't the value the code itself will get. Therefore, you can play around with it simply by setting the value of the `hash` variable directly in the code.

Anyway, assume this is your HTML:

```
<div>One</div>
<div>Two</div>
<div>Three</div>
```

Then your JavaScript would be:

```
$(function(){

    hash = window.location.hash

    index = parseInt(hash.replace('tab','')) - 1;

    if(isNaN(index)){ //if the hash isn't a valid tab
        index = 0;
    }

    $('div').eq(index).show();
});
```

You should probably also check first to make sure `$('div').eq(index)` actually exists, resorting to showing the first tab if it doesn't (just like we do if the hash analysis doesn't produce a legitimate value).